# Powershell script to check domain and install the application1 or or else it need to install application 2

Tags: powershell

I am writting a powershell script to install an application by checking its domain.

For example We have 2 domains and i need to create a single script to install the applciation with different IP address.

```
Function OnDomain{ 
    $QueryInfo = Get-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters -ErrorAction Stop        

    If($QueryInfo.Domain -eq "123.com"){ 

        Execute-MSI -Action Install -Path "$dirFiles\123\ud-agent-win32-x86.msi" -Parameters " CERTPATH=$dirFiles\123\Certs\ PORT=273 URL0=1.0.0.0 URL1=1.0.0.1 URL2=1.0.02 TIMEOUT=900 SOFTWAREUTILIZATION=ON PERIOD=90 SETUPTYPE=Enterprise /log C:\temp\ud_install\agent-install_East.log" 

    } elseIf($QueryInfo.Domain -eq "456.com"){ 

        Execute-MSI -Action Install -Path "$dirFiles\456\ud-agent-win32-x86.msi" -Parameters "/passive CERTPATH=$dirFiles\456\Certs\ Port=2738 URL0=2.0.0.0 URL1=2.0.0.1 URL2=2.0.0.3 TIMEOUT=900 SOFTWAREUTILIZATION=ON PERIOD=90" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: ok,  but what problem are you getting with this code ?

Comment: it only install for domain with 123.com.... If fails serach for another domain.

Comment: please update your question with exact error you get, if you have any error code, that will help others to understand the problem. Be detailed.

Comment: Have you checked if `$QueryInfo.Domain` ever is "456.com" ? Are your Parameters correct (they differ on both versions)

Comment: It works if i check for $QueryInfo.Domain as true  ..... It will show as 456.com